# Applying Observer-Observable pattern to a code and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, mvc, observer-pattern

I have to:

1) Apply the Observer-Observable pattern to the original code.

2) starting from the original code, I have to suppose that the modification of the array fields (slot machine numbers) should be done in parallel by 3 NumberGenerator threads instead of just one.

My output seems to work fine but I'm wondering if my implemention is good enough or if am I doing something wrong. Could you tell me if my code is good or not?

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class SlotMachineApp {

    private static final int N = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Numbers numeri = new Numbers(N);
        (new NumberGenerator(numeri)).start();
    }
}

class NumberGenerator extends Thread {

    private Numbers nums;

    public NumberGenerator(Numbers numeri) {
        nums = numeri;
    }

    public void run() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
            int index = r.nextInt(nums.getNum());
            nums.set(index, r.nextInt(5));
            nums.print();
            try {
                sleep((int) (Math.random() * 100));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Numbers {

    private final int[] items;

    public Numbers(int n) {
        items = new int[n];
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return items.length;
    }

    public void set(int index, int x) {
        items[index] = x;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(items[i] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < items.length - 1 && items[i] == items[i + 1]) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i >= items.length - 1) {
            System.out.println("ALL EQUAL!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

**OBSERVER-OBSERVABLE IMPLEMENTATION:**

**Model:**

```
    package slot;

    import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
    import java.util.Observable;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Model extends Observable {

        private static final int N = 3;
        Numbers numbers = new Numbers(N);
        NumberGenerator ng = new NumberGenerator(numbers);


        class NumberGenerator extends Thread {

           private Numbers nums;

           public NumberGenerator(Numbers numbers) {
              nums = numbers;
           }

            public void run() {
                Random r = new Random();
                for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
                    int index = r.nextInt(nums.getNum());
                    nums.set(index, r.nextInt(5));
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();
                    try {
                        sleep((int) (Math.random() * 100));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        class Numbers {

            private final int[] items;

            public Numbers(int n) {
                items = new int[n];
            }

            public int getNum() {
                return items.length;
            }

            public void set(int index, int x) {
                items[index] = x;
            }

            public void print() {
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(items[i] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
                int i = 0;
                while (i < items.length - 1 && items[i] == items[i + 1]) {
                    i++;
                }
                if (i >= items.length - 1) {
                    System.out.println("ALL EQUAL!!!!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
package slot;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class View implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof Model) {
            ((Model) o).numbers.print();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package slot;

public class Controller {

    private Model model;
    private View view;

    public Controller(Model m, View v){
        this.model = m;
        this.view =v;
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
package slot;

public class Slot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View();
        Controller controller = new Controller(model, view);
        model.addObserver(view);
        model.ng.start(); 
    }
}
```

MVC is not required I just like to use it for practice! If I did something wrong even in the MVC I would like to know please! I know that my Controller is doing nothing but actually I don't know which method to put inside to let Model and View comunicate since Observer-Observable calls update() from model to view.

**Thread - Implementation with 3 NumberGenerator:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class SlotMachineApp {

    private static final int N = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Numbers numbers = new Numbers(N);

        NumberGenerator ng1 = new NumberGenerator(numbers);
        NumberGenerator ng2 = new NumberGenerator(numbers);
        NumberGenerator ng3 = new NumberGenerator(numbers);

        ng1.start();
        ng2.start();
        ng3.start();
    }
}

class NumberGenerator extends Thread {

    private Numbers nums;

    public NumberGenerator(Numbers numbers) {
        nums = numbers;
    }

    public void run() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
            int index = r.nextInt(nums.getNum());
            nums.set(index, r.nextInt(5));
            nums.print();
            try {
                sleep((int) (Math.random() * 100));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Numbers {

    private final int[] items;

    public Numbers(int n) {
        items = new int[n];
    }

    public synchronized int getNum() {
        return items.length;
    }

    public synchronized void set(int index, int x) {
        items[index] = x;
    }

    public synchronized void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(items[i] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < items.length - 1 && items[i] == items[i + 1]) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i >= items.length - 1) {
            System.out.println("ALL EQUAL!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

I modified the getNum (), set(), and print() methods by adding the keyword synchronized because I think that in this way each thread can work on its own avoiding race condition.